# Pinvoke call always returns a -1

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, pinvoke

Visual Studio 2005 .NET SDK 2.0

We need to wrap the old C++ functions to open a handle to internal and external ports (the C# methods have too much overhead for our processors)

Here is the original C++ function:

```
extern "C" SERIALLIB_API HANDLE
OpenSerialConnection(TCHAR *port, int baudRate, int parity, int dataBits, int stopBits)
{
    // Open the serial device file driver
    HANDLE hSerial = CreateFile(port,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,    // must be opened with exclusive-access
        NULL, // default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING, // must use OPEN_EXISTING
        0,    // overlapped I/O not supported
        NULL  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
        );

RETAILMSG(1, (TEXT("Handle %d\n"),hSerial));

// Ensure the handle opened correctly
if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    RETAILMSG(1, (TEXT("INVALID HANDLE #1\n")));
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

// Set the handle to report only when there's
// a character to receive or when the transmit
// buffer is empty
if (!SetCommMask(hSerial, EV_RXCHAR|EV_TXEMPTY))
{
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    RETAILMSG(1, (TEXT("INVALID HANDLE #2\n")));
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

// The handle will now be configured to be the requested
// serial interface. The current settings are retrieved,
// and only the necessary settings are changed.
DCB dcb;
ZeroMemory(&dcb, sizeof(DCB));
dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);

BOOL fSuccess = GetCommState(hSerial, &dcb);
if (!fSuccess) 
{
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    RETAILMSG(1, (TEXT("INVALID HANDLE #3\n")));
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

// Fill in DCB with the desired settings
dcb.BaudRate = baudRate;   // set the baud rate
dcb.ByteSize = 8;             // data size, xmit, and rcv
dcb.Parity = parity;        // no parity bit
dcb.StopBits = stopBits;    // one stop bit

// Set the timeout values to make reading a synchronous activity.
// Reading from the serial line takes place in a separate thread,
// so this is what we want.
COMMTIMEOUTS timeout;
timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = MAXDWORD - 1;
timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = MAXDWORD;
timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;

if (!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeout) ||
    !SetCommState(hSerial, &dcb))
{
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    RETAILMSG(1, (TEXT("INVALID HANDLE #4\n")));
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

return hSerial;
}
```

The C# wrapper:

```
[DllImport("SerialLib.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenSerialConnection(string port, int baudRate, int parity, int dataBits, int stopBits);
```

And the call where handle is a IntPtr:

```
handle = Unmanaged.SerialWrapper.OpenSerialConnection(portName,
                                                                  baudRate,
                                                                  parityToInt(parity),
                                                                  dataBits,
                                                                  stopBitsToInt(stopBits));
```

No matter what I have the in the OpenSerialConnection C++ code the value of handle always comes back as a -1, I have stripped the function to just return an int value of 4 as a test.

I am completely stumped and all of my reading and searching are not proving to be helpful in solving this problem.

Any suggestions?

Edited to remove copy errors

*Solution:*

I had a two fold error going on.  With the suggestion from below to change the return values from the C++ to INT_PTR and a platform change I was able to get the call to return a valid handle.

Thank you very much for all of your assistance :)

Comment: Just making sure: you stripped the C++ function to simply `return 4;` and it still returns -1?

Comment: Try to define explicitly calling convention on both sides. Define CharSet in C# according to actual string type in C++ function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is converting a `HANDLE` into an `int`. On 64-bit platforms, this will result in truncation and data loss because `HANDLE` is 64 bits wide but `int` is only 32 bits wide. The compiler should have flagged that with (at least) a warning.

Try returning an `INT_PTR` from `OpenSerialConnection()` instead (and change the C# wrapper's return type accordingly).

Comment: That is copy error from when I had stripped the function just to return 4;

Comment: Original C++ function without the copy error and the C# wrapper

Comment: extern "C" SERIALLIB_API HANDLE
OpenSerialConnection(TCHAR *port, int baudRate, int parity, int dataBits, int stopBits)

Comment: @Ashley, and even if that function only returns `(HANDLE) 4`, you're seeing `-1` on the managed side?

Comment: @Frederic yes I see a -1 no matter what the C++ function contains, so I am thinking 2 things.. the data is getting corrupted somewhere, or the function isn't being called

Comment: @Ashley, can you tell us what does `SERIALLIB_API` resolve to?

Comment: #define SERIALLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)